# Global data sanitize utility plugin cakephp 2.6

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, xss, cakephp-2.6

I want to protect my CakePHP 2.6 website from XSS hacking. I come to know about the App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility'); 
Sanitize::clean();

I don't want write this function in my all controller since I lot of controller. Can anyone tell me the way to sanitize the data from appcontroller.php or any single point where i can write sanitize code.

I am sure there must be a place to validate all the fields from xss.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing HTML encode on controller is not a proper mitigation approach. In fact that performing HTML encode over every single input may can cause! another troubles.

For example, lets say user's firstname is O'neal. Automated mitigation libraries will change that single quote. Which means you are going to save a non-valid name to the database.

The solution is output encoding. Which is related to the framework's template engines. Most of the modern engines are forcing encoding over dangerous characters such as < or & etc.